# Routing all requests for different domains to different folders on the same root

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I posted a question up yesterday basically I have a single plan with winhost and I want to be able to have multiple domains (that are all pointed at my root) go to different subfolders and in these sub-folders I host different MVC apps. A very helpful chap took me most of the way but (and I know its lame how difficult im finding this) but I really cannot work out how to do the final peice...

The IIS config...

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect if producerpte" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^producerpte/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="producerpte/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

works brilliantly. When I now go to http://www.producerpte.co.uk I can see my site in the subfolder but the url looks like its on the root. However I also want to try and host my girlfriends site so I have tried multiple combinations but I just cannot seem to add rules that will work for both sites...I know I need to add two more rules like this...

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
             <rules><!--first site-->
                <rule name="Redirect if producerpte" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^producerpte/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder producerpte">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="producerpte/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                     <!--second site-->
                <rule name="Redirect if samyoga" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^samyoga/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder samyoga">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="samyoga/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Whatever it is about the last rule I just cant get it to route. If I use it then when I go to Samyoga.co.uk I end up at Samyoga.co.uk/producerpte ?????

I tried matching the wildcard in the second rule (for each site) it just doesnt work at all then.....

Comment: why try to use many apps? may be better would be to create 1 app for all subdomains and in this app do any logic your need?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using multiple websites with domain specific bindings? That is the tool designed for this situation.

Comment: im using multiple apps because i want to create multiple apps on 1 account with winhost....Does anyone know how to do this?